# How to manually pass username & password to get SharePoint 2010 List data via Excel VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, macos, sharepoint-2010

**Objective** - Get SharePoint List data into Excel via Excel VBA Code specifically.

**Issue** - The following code loads the list values into Excel as expected, BUT i want to ***pass username & password manually*** using the same code so i can change the credentials as per the need.

**Technology Used** - SharePoint 2010 and Excel VBA.

**Complete Code:**

```
Sub RCAFunc()
Dim objMyList As ListObject*emphasized text*
Dim objWksheet As Worksheet
Dim strSPServer As String
Const SERVER As String = "intranet.xyz.com/Ops/RCA/"
Const LISTNAME As String = "{15f4dl02-iz9g-496o-uh9q-6br0984bb9tw}"
Const VIEWNAME As String = "294O2P46-ZC5S-4ETL-BQC9-4I234A4C4025"
' The SharePoint server URL pointing to
' the SharePoint list to import into Excel.
strSPServer = "http://" & SERVER & "/_vti_bin"
' Add a new worksheet to the active workbook.
'Set objWksheet = Worksheets.Add
Set objWksheet = Worksheets("MySheet1")
' Add a list range to the newly created worksheet
' and populated it with the data from the SharePoint list.
Set objMyList = objWksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, Array(strSPServer, LISTNAME, VIEWNAME), True, , Range("a1"))
Set objMyList = Nothing
Set objWksheet = Nothing

Call MyList1
'MsgBox ("Task Completed!")

End Sub

Sub MyList1()
 Dim wrksht As Worksheet
 Dim objListObj As ListObject

 Set wrksht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet1")
 Set objListObj = wrksht.ListObjects(1)
 objListObj.Unlist
End Sub
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify why you need this, if you'd use this to distribute some data to others, then you could set the permissions on sharepoint so others can access the data as well.

If thats not possible(?) then you could use OLEDB connection to sharepoint, in which you set the user credentials.

However if this file will be distributed than storing username and password in vba plain text code, is a very very bad idea.

Comment: Firstly, i cannot make any changes on server side, no access. Secondly, i have shared the working code, could you please add some code using OLEDB connection on the same, would be a great help. Yes, we want to store the credentials in VBA as Excel will be password protected. Thanks!

Comment: Excel password protected documents are very insecure and can be easily opened. I would use file encryption for sensitive information like this.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i set username & password in the above VBA code to get SharePoint list data?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/54e32c6a-64bd-41f0-b24b-b6d6bf2aa9b6/trouble-inserting-into-sharepoint-access-db-with-adodb-connection?forum=accessdev in In the above VBA code, im affraid you cant, but check this out.

Answer (score 0):

I found [This connection string reference](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sharepoint/) which suggests that you can append the username and password to the URL.

You may be also able to manually supply credentials by running Excel with the credentials, as VBA normally runs in the same context as the application.

Alternatively you could look to get the data via ADO which should allow you to set the credentials in the connection string. [Here is an example](https://scottlyerly.wordpress.com/2014/05/14/excel-geeking-using-vba-and-ado-to-pull-data-from-sharepoint-lists/)